# Как правильно: 16 военнослужащИЙ или 16 военнослужащИХ?

Tags: грамматика

Согласно правилам, если определение стоит после счетного оборота, оно должно принимать форму мн.ч. им.пад. А какой падеж нужен здесь? Я склоняюсь к род.пад. Прошу ответ дать ответ,основываясь на правиле.

Ранения различной степени тяжести получили и были госпитализированы 16 военнослужащий срочной службы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно: Ранения различной степени тяжести получили и были госпитализированы 16 военнослужащих срочной службы.

**Прилагательные, перешедшие в существительные,**  сочетаются с числительными два, три, четыре только во мн. числе Р.п.: три морских животных,  два насекомых, сравнить: три  медведя  (ед.ч.)

Эти четыре морских  животных  подробно описаны в книге. На удочку лучше насаживать по два насекомых.

С другими числительными прилагательные, перешедшие в существительные, сочетаются **на общих правилах,** а именно: числительное задает существительному Р.п.  в начальной форме (были награждены шестнадцать военнослужащих) и согласуется с существительным в косвенных падежах (шестнадцати военнослужащим была оказана помощь).

Comment: Но здесь ведь нет этих числительных.